# Sending data from Salesforce to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, salesforce

Im using Salesforce to store recruitment details and job positions. I'm building a WordPress site, and I was wondering if there was a way I can use SalesForces API to automate sending the data to WordPress, so I can publish job opportunities, for example?

Has anyone had any experience with automating data from SalesForce to Wordpress? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Zapier](https://zapier.com/zapbook/wordpress/)?  It has connectors to both Salesforce and Wordpress.  Without more detail I can't say if it can do what you want, but it might be worth checking out.